# Can't make MSMPI to work. It always says "mpi.h: No such file or directory gcc"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ms-mpi

So I've tried multiple times to make MSMPI to work, however it still says that it can't find mpi.h

I've added to Include Path for C\C++ Extension in VS Code ${MSMPI_INC} and configured tasks.json, as people said (added "-I", "${MSMPI_INC}", "-L","${MSMPI_LIB64}", "-lmsmpi") but it still says that there is no mpi.h
Seen similar topic, but they all were about mpi for linux, but no one posted answer for MSMPI
It all works in CLion, but the free trial ends soon, so I decided to move to VS Code
Thanks in advance

UPD: Here's a JSON file

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-I",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include/",
            "-L",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x64/",
            "-lmsmpi",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And a build log:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\Coding\ParallelProgramming\Test\main.c -o D:\Coding\ParallelProgramming\Test\main.exe
D:\Coding\ParallelProgramming\Test\main.c:5:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
#include <mpi.h>
             ^
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

UPD2: Changed JSON to

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build with MSMPI",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mpiexec",
        "args": [
            "-n",
            "1",
            "gcc",
            "${file}",
            "-I C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include/",
            "-L C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x64/",
            "-lmsmpi",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
    }
]
}
```

It didn't help

Comment: Welcome to SO. What happens if you replace the variables `MSMPI_INC` etc. with their content? I doubt that VSCode allows using these variables in the json files.

Comment: I've put adresses like "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include/" instead of variables and still the same issue

Comment: Maybe it helps if you show your json file(s) instead of describing fragmentsof it. Unfortunately. And also show your build log. What command is used to compile and what error message is shown. Please copy complete and exact message into the question. Add as formatted text, no pictures please.

Comment: Please post relevant information directly into the question. External links might go stale makind the question useless.

Comment: Sorry. Added build log and JSON

Comment: I can't open that json link. The command line does not show any hint of `"-I", "...", "-L", "...", "-lmspmi"` which you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, there is some problem in your JSON file `task.json` adjust the file to properly include the MPI headers and libraries, try this

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build with MSMPI",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mpiexec",
            "args": [
                "-n",
                "1",
                "gcc",
                "${file}",
                "-I${MSMPI_INC}",
                "-L${MSMPI_LIB64}",
                "-lmsmpi",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

replace ${MSMPI_INC} and ${MSMPI_LIB64} with the correct paths to the MPI include directory and library directory respectively.

edit:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build with MSMPI",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mpiexec",
            "args": [
                "-n",
                "1",
                "gcc",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include",
                "-L",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x64",
                "-lmsmpi",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Changed tasks.json, but it still says that there is no such file or directory

Comment: there might be an issue with how you're passing the include and library paths to the compiler in your tasks.json file (see the edited code now)